# useReducer value not being updated properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to update a state of a component with useReducer. I'm grabbing some info from mongodb in useEffect and there I am calling my useReducer dispatch so I can set my state as soon as the component mounts. Unfortunately, my state isn't being affected and my UI isn't changing. The console.log statement at the end of my useEffect statement shows my state to still have the initial values set in useReducer call. Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong here? Also, I plan on later adding to the state and to the dependency array in useEffect. Before when I was working on this, I was getting an infinite useEffect loop so for now I have an empty error. I'd like to update the state though and have my UI reflect the changes. Anways, here is the code of the functional component containing the useEffect call.

EDIT: my_player object should originally be this object for the user I am currently using with mongodb {health_percent: 100, hunger_percent: 100, hydration_percent: 100}

```
const change_progress_color = (pet_percentage: any) => {
    // change the attribute's color depending on pet_attr value
    // PROGRESS_COLORS IS JUST AN ENUM OBJ WITH COLOR CODES
    let color;
    if (pet_percentage < .10)
        color = PROGRESS_COLORS[1];
    else if (pet_percentage < .30)
        color = PROGRESS_COLORS[2];
    else if (pet_percentage < .50)
        color = PROGRESS_COLORS[3];
    else if (pet_percentage < .75)
        color = PROGRESS_COLORS[4];
    else if (pet_percentage < .90)
        color = PROGRESS_COLORS[5];
    else
        color = PROGRESS_COLORS[6];
    return color;
};

const Player: React.FC = () => {
    const [player, setPlayer] = useState<any>();
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<React.Reducer<State, Actions>>(reducer,
        {health: 0, hydration: 0, hunger: 0});

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("running useEffect");
        (async () => {
            var my_player = await getPlayer();
            if (my_player)
                if (my_player.length > 0) {
                    const p: any = my_player[0];
                    setPlayer(p);
                    console.log("here is my player", p);
                    dispatch({type: "ChangeHealth", diff: p.health_percent});
                    dispatch({type: "ChangeHunger", diff: p.hunger_percent});
                    dispatch({type: "ChangeHydration", diff: p.hydration_percent});
                    console.log("Here is my state", state);
                }
        })();
    }, []);
    return (
            <IonPage>
                <IonHeader>
                    <IonToolbar>
                        <IonTitle>My Player</IonTitle>
                    </IonToolbar>
                </IonHeader>
                <IonContent>
                    <IonHeader collapse="condense">
                        <IonToolbar>
                            <IonTitle size="large">My Player</IonTitle>
                        </IonToolbar>
                    </IonHeader>
                    <IonList>
                        <IonItem>
                            <IonLabel position="floating">
                                Health
                            </IonLabel>
                            <IonProgressBar
                                value={state.health}
                                color={change_progress_color(state.health)}/>
                        </IonItem>
                        <IonItem>
                            <IonLabel position="floating">
                                Hunger
                            </IonLabel>
                            <IonProgressBar
                                value={state.hunger}
                                color={change_progress_color(state.hunger)}/>
                        </IonItem>
                        <IonItem>
                            <IonLabel position="floating">
                                Hydration
                            </IonLabel>
                            <IonProgressBar
                                value={state.hydration}
                                color={change_progress_color(state.hydration)}/>
                        </IonItem>
                    </IonList>
                </IonContent>
            </IonPage>
    );
};

export default Player;
```

Here is my code outside the react function with my types and reducer function.

```
type State = {
    health: number;
    hunger: number;
    hydration: number;
};

type ChangeHealth = {
    readonly type: "ChangeHealth";
    readonly diff: number;  // this number is going to need to be divided by 100
}

type ChangeHunger = {
    readonly type: "ChangeHunger";
    readonly diff: number; // this number is going to need to be divided by 100
}

type ChangeHydration = {
    readonly type: "ChangeHydration";
    readonly diff: number; // this number is going to need to be divided by 100
}


type Actions = ChangeHealth | ChangeHunger | ChangeHydration;

function reducer(state: State, action: Actions): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ChangeHealth":
            return (() => {
                console.log("running func");
                console.log("here is the diff ", action.diff);
                let new_health = (state.health + action.diff) / 100;
                console.log(new_health);
                if (new_health > 1)
                    new_health = 1;
                return {...state, health: new_health};
            } )();
        case "ChangeHunger":
            return (() => {
                let new_hunger = (state.hunger + action.diff) / 100;
                if (new_hunger > 1)
                    new_hunger = 1;
                return {...state, hunger: new_hunger};
            } )();
        case "ChangeHydration":
            return (() => {
                let new_hydration = (state.hydration + action.diff) / 100;
                if (new_hydration > 1)
                    new_hydration = 1;
                return {...state, hydration: new_hydration};
            } )();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the whole Player component with its html?

Comment: @AleksandreJavakhishvili just did. Thanks for looking at my question. So basically I want these values to update so I can use them in my IonProgress bars. Based on those state values, I'll change the color of the progress bar too

Comment: I have one more question, what does this line `console.log("here is my player", p);` logs?

Comment: @AleksandreJavakhishvili I get back an object with my player _id, my user id and the following keys health_percent, hunger_percent, hydration_percent are all 100. So I am passing in values to dispatch that are defined and greater than 0

Comment: @AleksandreJavakhishvili Also want to note that I at one point thought calling dispatch() in useEffect could be the issue but I created a button (now removed) in my component with onClick containing an arrow function with a call to one of the same dispatch() from useEffect but that didn't update the value either

Comment: Can you add this code `console.log("State",state);` right below the useEffect hook, before the return statement and please comment the log.

Comment: @AleksandreJavakhishvili I have three logs. I'd imagine useEffect is causing a rerender after each change.  State {health: 1, hydration: 0, hunger: 0} and State {health: 1, hydration: 0, hunger: 1} and State {health: 1, hydration: 1, hunger: 1}. So it looks like they are updating. The real question than is what am I doing wrong with what I'm returning and i don't know why my last print statement in useEffect still shows "here is my state {health: 0, hydration: 0, hunger: 0}

Comment: The reason why last console.log in useEffect printed wrong state because, dispatch(it is not synchronous) method causes the re-render and new state will be updated in new render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your useEffect and Reducer code is fine, state is Updated as you expected, the reason why the last console.log was not logging the new state is because, dispatch method is not synchronous, it causes re-render and on the next render new state will be updated. I think your problem is displaying the state 
             `<IonProgressBar value={state.hydration} color={change_progress_color(state.hydration)}/>`.

Comment: Just found out that ion isn't liking the colors I am supplying to my progress bar. Everything else is in working order though. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You make only one request. For what reason do you split data to useState and useReduce?

MB code bellow helps you.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Player: React.FC = () => {
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState({
    health: 0,
    hydration: 0,
    hunger: 0,
  });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getPlayer()
      .then((response) => {
        const [player] = response;

        if (player) {
          setPlayer((prevState) => {
            const health = (prevState.health + player.health_percent) / 100;
            const hunger = (prevState.hunger + player.hunger_percent) / 100;
            const hydration = (prevState.hydration + player.hydration_percent) / 100;

            return ({
              health: health > 1 ? 1 : health,
              hunger: hunger > 1 ? 1 : hunger,
              hydration: hydration > 1 ? 1 : hydration,
            });
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(({ message }) => {
        console.error(message);
      });
  }, []);

  return null;
};
```

Comment: I wanted to try out useReducer(1st time user) and wanted to see if I could fix my infinite useEffect loop issue when I set dependencies in second arg array to useEffect()